# Footer bottom of the screen

Tags: html, css, position, footer

I found a lot of articles about this subject but none off it will work for me, i want to make a footer that's on the bottom of the screen when the content isn't large enough, but when the content is longer than the screen that my footer stays under the content and doesn't stick at the bottom of the screen.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is just another example how to do it, works fine in all browsers AFAIK.
http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/examples/csslayout1.html

**Edit:** I am not the author, just looked myself for something like that some time ago.

Comment: I used that exact code and it does this: http://gyazo.com/28d5dd1e1893d0c9f264cb9c8bd70b5c

Comment: This works, i had a problem in my code my height of the body was set to 100 and not 100%..

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Try [CSS Sticky Footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/): it is nice and CSS-only.

If you want to experiment, `absolute` CSS position property could also work. Checkout [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position):

```
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: I just want it at the bottom of the page not at the bottom of the screen, so when the content is small that it is on the bottom of the screen, but when the content is large that you need to scroll down to see the footer.

Comment: Now I undestand, I suggest trying to adapt CSS Sticky Footer to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quite easy to do this just with CSS, though there are some minor restrictions. Here is a demo of how it's done (view source to get the code):

http://www.pmob.co.uk/temp/sticky-footer-ie8new-no-table.htm

Here is a detailed explanation of how it works, in case you need it:

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?171943-CSS-FAQ-Tips-etc-Please-read-before-posting!&p=1239966#post1239966

Comment: It's at the bottom when the content is big enough, but when the content is small it comes up :(

Comment: How so? Just open demo provided and footer stayed at the bottom although content doesn't even take half a screen.

Comment: Indeed. You need to follow the example code very carefully. If you don't, it will screw up.

Answer (score 0):

-- do it by javascript

-- example

```
<div class='content'>
  your page
</div>
<div class='Footer'>Footer</div>

<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var document_height = $(document).height();
 var content_height = $('.content').height();

 if (content_height < document_height) {
    $('.content').css('height', (document_height));
 }
</script>
```