# How to put footer on bottom for small webpage on large screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a small web page. I am trying to place a footer on the bottom of the page. On mobile, it naturally shows nicely, when the user scrolls to the end. But on a desktop, the footer shows in the middle of the window.

How can I have the footer place on the bottom of the screen, but not in the sticky way, where it is always on the bottom of the screen, I just to avoid it being in the middle of the window on a screen that is larger than the content of the web page.

I am looking for a solution with either Bootstrap or pure CSS.

Here is an example of how my page is, see
http://jsbin.com/cibixegeqi/edit?html,css,output

Code:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <h1>Some content</h1>
    <p>This is a really small web page. On a standard mobile it is a little more than a screen, but on a laptop it is only half a window.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <b>This is my footer.</b> I want it to be on the bottom of the window, but not sticky, just want to avoid that it is in the middle of the screen on a larger screen.
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you please provide your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Footer bottom of the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382823/footer-bottom-of-the-screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Css** :

```
html, body{height:100%;}
#footer{position:absolute;bottom:0;}
```

Should work...

**Update** for long body: *(try to set a height for the footer, so you can set a padding to the body)*

```
html{height:100%;}
body{padding-bottom:50px;min-height:100%;position:relative;}
#footer{position:absolute;bottom:0;height:50px;}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this create a problem when text is overlapping with the footer:
http://jsbin.com/vojucokavu/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @Armin Try with my update (so the title is not just for the small webpage ;-)  )

Comment: @pbenard Problem doesn't seem to be fixed on my side. But in general, I am just raising a question for future viewers :)

Comment: @Armin Excuse me, I forgot the position relative to the body, it works (should)

Comment: @pbenard Seems to be better now.

Answer (score 1):

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

```
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Added the code, but no change, see http://output.jsbin.com/cibixegeqi I will read the article and see if there is more to it. Thanks!